# Cloudformation UserData with Elastic IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a simple cloudformation script that builds a Server ("AWS::EC2::Instance") and an Elastic IP ("AWS::EC2::EIP") which it attaches to that server.

The subnet has an igw attached.

I also have UserData defined within the Properties of the Server. The problem is that until the EIP attaches to the Server, there is no internet connectivity. Since this is an internet-facing subnet and I don't have a NAT box/gateway configured, is there a best practice for delaying UserData until the EIP attaches?

There is a dependency issue here:  Server is created, EIP is created and attach to server ("InstanceId":{"Ref":"Server"}), so I don't believe I can DependsOn with the EIP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you add DependsOn for the EC2 creation till EIP is created. Having a Ref to EIP doesnt guarantee that the instance will wait till EIP is created.

Comment: Good thought. I made a few adjustments such that the elastic ip is created first, the server second, and then an IP association ("AWS::EC2::EIPAssociation") third (using DependsOn).

This fixed the issue.  Interestingly, looks like I could use the NetworkInterface / AssociatePublicIpAddress property in the CFN script to have this happen automatically.  I've not tested that yet but probably will tomorrow. Thanks for the help!